# Is it safe to expose the keychain password when codesigning in GitHub workflow?

Tags: macos, code-signing

I'm on a project where I need to automatically codesign my Mac OS app. Currently my approach is to create a keychain in the workflow, add the certificate, codesign my app, and delete the keychain.

My question is, If the temporary password I used for the keychain is exposed in the workflow file, will there be any security vulneribilities?

Since the keychain is immediately destroyed, I don't see any problem with it. Or does it affect the content of the signature, and we are't supposed to expose it?

Comment: the problem is not the temporary password. however, you will need to upload your private key to a 3rd party entity (namely: GitHub). "private" means "do not give it to anybody", so uploading it to some webservice inherently breaks the trust.